# HighCharts: To restrict the length of bars in wind rose chart

Tags: highcharts

We are facing issue in wind rose chart when displaying real data. The data values range from very small (100) to very large (1000000000). On rendering the data set in wind rose chart, as the max length has to be set according to the highest value, the smaller values are not visible.

As a workaround to this, we planned to restrict the length of the bars/ spikes in the chart to say 10px so that all the values are visible. But couldn't find a way to do so. In bar chart we can use minPointLength property.

Can anyone provide any help on how to restrict the length of bars or any other workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `type: 'logarithmic'` axis, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3pEbJ/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. It worked in our case. Would like to add few points for the modifications required for using this property.
1. On using “type: 'logarithmic'” property, if the data series contains value 0 for any value, JavaScript will throw error #10  ‘Can't plot zero or subzero values on a logarithmic axis’. To avoid this error you need to change the zero value to some non-zero value. This scenario occurs for stacked series.
2. Providing non-zero value will render that value in tooltip also. So as a workaround, we can provide the non-zero value like 0.00001. This way it will display value 0 in the tooltip for that series and also the corresponding bar would be very small.